# Running htlatex in a shell script (bash, mac)

Tags: htlatex

I am trying to simply run a command:

```
htlatex texfilename "xhtml,charset=utf-8"
```

In a terminal command line, it runs well. If I create a shell script file that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
htlatex texfilename "xhtml,charset=utf-8"
```

It produces the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.

*
```

and stops.

How can I make this work? Should I give some options to `htlatex`? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed " ", and it worked good.

```
#!/bin/bash  
htlatex texfilename xhtml,charset=utf-8
```

Thanks.